# How can I make an HTML form button?

Tags: php, html, forms

This is the piece of script that I'm working with; I'm trying to use a button in place of the "AddtoCart" link.  How can I use a button, here?

```
<body>
<div id=cart align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
<h1 align="center">Products</h1>
    <?php
        $sql = "SELECT serial, name, description, price,picture FROM products;";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        while(list($id, $name, $description, $price,$picture) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align=left>";
            echo "<a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=$id\">Add To Cart</a>"; ===> here i want to get button having value like "Add To Cart"
            echo "<hr color=grey size=\"0\" >";         
            echo "</td>";   
            echo "</tr>";           
        }   
    ?>  
</table>
<a href="cart.php">View Cart</a>
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<input type="button" />`?

Comment: This is somewhat unclear, but if I understand correctly you just need to create a form and then populate the value field with the button desired. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: **echo "<a href=\"cart.php?action=add&id=$id\">Add To Cart</a>"; ===> here i want to get button having value like "Add To Cart"**  This thing i want like a button thanks

Comment: -1 The OP isn't really going to much effort to solve the problem. A quick search on Google reveals lots of answers to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript if you like **(Edited)**:

```
echo    "<input type='button' onClick=\"window.open('cart.php?action=add&id=" . $id . "','_self');\" value='Add to Cart' />";
```

Comment: Yes the button is coming..no linking done.but am not getting  what is **_parent** in your code

Comment: Try _self maybe, it tells the browser to load the page in the same window/tab. If you want it to open in another tab, use _blank.

Comment: I have added _parent , _blank and _self none of them are not going to **cart.php?action=add&id=(any number)** page...

Comment: Ok I tested this and it works: echo    "<input type='button' onClick=\"window.open('cart.php?action=add&id=" . $id . "','_self');\" value='Add to Cart' />";

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could hep :)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Style the `<a>` tag like a button with CSS. Use `border-radius` for rounded corners, and box-shadow.
2. Use a `<button>` tag, with an AJAX call on the 'click' event.

Use the latter if you want the default OS styling of the button (e.g. OS X Safari buttons will look like all other OS X Safari buttons, Firefox will look like Firefox, etc). If this is not important, the first option is a little bit easier to code.

Comment: Not sure how to do first step...  **Style the <a> tag like a button with CSS. Use border-radius for rounded corners, and box-shadow.**

Comment: There are quite a few tutorials available for this - just search on Google. e.g. http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa041904.htm, http://speckyboy.com/2009/05/27/22-css-button-styling-tutorials-and-techniques/

Comment: Blowski...good solution..it worked..but it is not looking like a button..looks like a rectangle box inside text...

Comment: OK, just search on Google for what you need - there are thousands of pages covering this very issue.